# Passing data From ListView Item to next Form

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I know how to send data from an Entry, Label to the next Form , but how can i do this with a ListView. 
I want a simple direct approach.

My XAML code :

```
<ListView x:Name="MyClientslistView" HasUnevenRows="true"  ItemTapped="OnSalesReport">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>

                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="Center"  Margin="5" >
                                <Label Text="{Binding client_name}" TextColor="#A7A392" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding client_address}" TextColor="Black" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding client_phone}"  TextColor="Black" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding client_email}"  TextColor="Black" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding AssignStatus}"  TextColor="Black" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding assignmentComments}"  TextColor="Black" />
                            </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

I already have loaded data from JSON to the ListView , now currently i want to move each ID on he Item to the Next Form , how can i tackle that ?

Comment: Do you want to pass the entire list? Do you only want to pass the ID of the item someone tapped on or ?

Comment: cant you just send the ItemSource of the ListView to next form?

Comment: Maybe you could load your data into a `list`, and then use it as the `Listview ItemsSource`. Another way if you don't want to change your existing code is to use two way binding on the listview `ItemSources="{Binding NameOfYourList, Mode=TwoWay}"` and the pass the list to the next form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the item from `ItemTapped` listener. In your case use below solution.

```
void OnSalesReport(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        YourItemModel item = (YourItemModel)((ListView)sender).SelectedItem;
        ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
        Navigation.PushAsync(new NextPage(item));
    }
```

Comment: My YourItemModel Class has attributes like ID , Name etc is your answer saying that i can call them here , please rectify that

Comment: i may be missing a trick here, why are you using "(YourItemModel)((ListView)sender).SelectedItem" and not "(YourItemModel)e.Item;"

Answer (score 1):

> Sorry for the poor english

You can have your entire item at your event handler `private void OnSalesReport(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)` through `e.Item`.
You must do `var item = ((YourTypeClassItem)e.Item);` then you get things like `item.client_name` and probably `item.client_id`.

I hope it helps you.